# Unable to change the pointer value in class

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to build a BST in C++, the root node inside class was not affecting when in call insert() function, it remains NULL.
I am passing root to insert_tree() function when I need to insert data into the tree but when I try to print root value inside insert_tree it always returning NULL

```
#include <iostream>
struct node
{
    int value;
    node *left;
    node *right;

};

class bst
{
private:
node *root; 
    node* insert(node* parent,int value)
    {
        if(parent== NULL){
            parent = new node;
            parent->value = value;
            parent->left = parent->right = NULL;

        }
        else if(parent->value>value){
            parent->left = insert(parent->left,value);
        }
        else{
            parent->right=insert(parent->right,value);
        }

        return parent;
    }
    void display(node* parent){
        if(parent != NULL){
        display(parent->left);
        std::cout << parent->value <<"\t";
        display(parent->right);
        }
    }
public:
    bst(){
        root = NULL;    
    }

    void insert(int value){
        root = insert(root,value);
    }
    void display(){
        display(root);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    bst b1;
    b1.insert(10);
    b1.insert(1);
    b1.insert(11);
    b1.insert(9);
    b1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bst(){
        root = NULL;    
    }` - you should a) be using the initialization list. And b) use `nullptr`, *not* `NULL`. Also, your code will leak if exceptions are thrown - investigate smart pointers and stop doing manual memory mnagement. `using namespace std;` is a bad habit that *will* eventually bite you. I'd suggest returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` from `main` in portable programs (`0` is not success everywhere). And more, but that's what fits in a comment.

Comment: When you used a *debugger*, which line is causing the issue?  Please highlight.

Comment: You are passing pointers by value. Use pass by reference if you want the pointer to change in the caller.

Comment: `insert_tree` gets a copy of the pointer, and modifying it doesn't affect the original one. Learn how to pass the pointer by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you read about BST first [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-data-structure/) and learn how insertion is done in a BST. First of all the algorithm is wrong and secondly, use `pass by reference` in `insert_tree()` function instead of `pass by value`. As you are passing by value, so the value of root doesn't change.